# Printing asterisks using for loops in java

Tags: java, python, for-loop

In python, to print

```
******
 *****
  ****
   ***
    **
     *

     *
    **
   ***
  ****
 *****
******
```

We would code the following:

```
for e in range (11,0,-1):
    print((11-e) * ' ' + e * '*')

print ('')
for g in range (11,0,-1):
    print(g * ' ' + (11-g) * '*')
```

My question is, can this be done in Java as well?
Java doesn't let you multiply a string (int) times, e.g. `4 * " "`, so how can we implement this in java?

Comment: @ergonaut I want to convert the above code to python, without using external libraries or imports

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code translation service.

Comment: the above code is in python! Boom hope i helped

Comment: He is asking how to write spaces multiple times.  He isn't asking for translation.

Comment: Why did you tag with Java?

Comment: @Tim I had a curious moment and I wanted to know how to implement that in java.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I know it's not a code translation service. I just wanted to know how to multiply a string in Java, since it seems much more complicated than the way they do it in python.

Comment: It isn't more complicated.  It might be more verbose, but you can always encapsulate it in a method.

Comment: @ergonaut yes, verbose is a more fitting word, thanks

Comment: You can do the whole thing in one single loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't be a concise:

```
    // top half..
    for (int i=11;i>0;i--){
        for (int a=0;a<11-i;a++){
            System.out.print(' ');
        }
        for (int b=0;b<i;b++){
            System.out.print('*');
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I print the bottom half?

Comment: Seriously?  As @TigerhawkT3 says, this isn't a code translation service.  Having said that, you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: going back on this, I'd like to say that I did figure it out myself

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Loops {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      //print first half
      for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
          printChar(' ', i);
          printChar('*', 6-i);
          System.out.println();
      }        

      //print second half
      for(int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
         printChar(' ', 6-i);
         printChar('*', i);
         System.out.println();
      }
      System.out.println();
    }

    //helper function to print a char n specific times
    private static void printChar(char ch, int n) {
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print(ch);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `printchar` isn't a thing!

Comment: It is if you define it as a function.

Comment: it is being defined as a function

Comment: You don't need two `for` loops.

Comment: That's why. I just ran this without creating the class. my bad,

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I was just trying to provide a very simple answer

Answer (score 0):

To run through a string multiple times in Java, you can use a for loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < yournum; i++){
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

`yournum` is the number of spaces you want

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Core Java solution which can generate the entire output using a single `for` loop:

```
String before = "", after = "";

for (int i=0; i < 6; ++i) {
    String starRepeat = String.format("%0" + (6-i) + "d", 0).replace("0", "*");
    String spaceRepeat = (i>0) ? String.format("%0" + i + "d", 0).replace("0", " ") : "";
    String line = spaceRepeat + starRepeat;

    if (i == 0) {
        before = line;
        after = line;
    }
    else {
        before = before + "\n" + line;
        after = line + "\n" + after;
    }
}

System.out.println(before + "\n\n" + after);
```

**Output:**

```
******
 *****
  ****
   ***
    **
     *

     *
    **
   ***
  ****
 *****
******
```

Comment: Thanks, this was useful!

Answer (score 0):

```
    IntStream.range(0, 6).forEach(i -> {
        IntStream.range(0, i)
                .forEach(t -> System.out.print(" "));
        IntStream.range(0, 6 - i)
                .forEach(t -> System.out.print("*"));
        System.out.println();
    });
```

In `Java8` you can use `Stream` to do the samething. Use `IntStream` to `range` and `println`

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to using: Commons Lang StringUtils ...
using Commons Lang StringUtils.repeat() can help you repeat a string...
as an example:

```
StringUtils.repeat("*", 3) //produces ***
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score -2):

You can add the message you want to print on a String, then print out the string value by `System.out.println(message);`